# How to move spotlight back to the top right corner in El Captain?

Tags: macos, spotlight

I guess Apple got a bit too literal with the "Spotlight" feature. I feel far too sceptical about upgrading to El Captain just because of my most favourite feature, the Spotlight smacks right at you in the middle of the screen. Is there any way at all to bring spotlight to where it was back in the good old 10.9 Mavericks?

Answer (score 2):

You can click and drag the Spotlight search field anywhere on the screen and it will stay there.